# How to show/hide specific cell in a data view web part SharePoint Designer 2007 on dropdown change

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint:dvdropdownlist dropdown that is pulling options from a list and then will write back these changes once the user submits. However, there are certain fields that we would like to be able to hide or show based on the value of the dropdown, on change.

Trying to use jquery, but with little success.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

 $(document).ready(function($) {
     var selected = $("#SharePoint:dvdropdownlist option:selected").text();
    if (selected == 'Other')
     {
        $("#OtherReason").hide();
    }
});


</SCRIPT>
```

Your thoughts?

Comment: i'm new to sharepoint in my new job ... i hate sharepoint ... futher proof microsoft hates programmers ...